# Partial sum of pochhammer symbols and fractial

Tags: summation

Is the following evaluation of the sum correct?

$$\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{(\frac{1}{2})_n}{n!} \frac{(\frac{1}{2})_{k-n}}{(k-n)!} =1.$$

I don't see how this is immediate from the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check that for $k=2$:

$$\frac 1{0!}\frac {\left(\frac12\right)\left(-\frac12\right)}{2!}+\frac {\frac12}{1!}\frac{\frac12}{1!}+\frac {\left(\frac12\right)\left(-\frac12\right)}{2!}\frac 1{0!}=0\ne1$$

In fact:
$$\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{(\frac{1}{2})_n}{n!} \frac{(\frac{1}{2})_{k-n}}{(k-n)!} =\sum_{n=0}^k\binom {\frac12}n\binom{\frac12}{k-n} = \binom {\frac12+\frac12}k=\binom1k=\begin{cases}1 &\text{for }k=0,1\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The equality used is the [Chu-Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity).

Comment: You can see that Wikipedia has a [wrong Pochhammer Symbol definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). You can compare, for instance, with MathWorld and DLMF.

Comment: Says the person who didn't even read through the second paragraph of the MathWorld definition.

Comment: the case k=2 equals to 1, check wolfram alpha

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{equation}
\mbox{Note that}\quad
\pars{a}_{n} = a^{\overline{n}} =
{\Gamma\pars{a + n} \over \Gamma\pars{a}} =
{\pars{a + n - 1}! \over \pars{a - 1}!}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
In (\ref{1}), I'm using the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2.iii), [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) and [Wolfram-${\tt Mathematica}$](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pochhammer.html)
*definitions*.

Wikipedia, I guess, has a
[wrong definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
$\require{cancel}\ds{\cancel{\pars{x}_{n} = x^{\underline{n}} =
x\pars{x - 1}\ldots\pars{x - n + 1}}}$.

---

With (\ref{1}):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 0}^{k}{\pars{1/2}_{n} \over n!}\,
{\pars{1/2}_{k - n} \over \pars{k - n}!}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\color{red}{\infty}}{\pars{n - 1/2}!\,/\pars{-1/2}! \over n!}\,
{\pars{k - n - 1/2}!\,/\pars{-1/2}! \over
\color{red}{\pars{k - n}!}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n - 1/2 \choose n}{k - n - 1/2 \choose k - n} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}}
\bracks{{-1/2 \choose k - n}\pars{-1}^{k - n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{k}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{-1/2 \choose n}\bracks{z^{k - n}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{k}\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose n}z^{n} =
\pars{-1}^{k}\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}
\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{k}\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1} =
\pars{-1}^{k}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{k}} = \bbx{\large 1} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: in the first line, how did you get the upper limit to be at infinity?

Comment: @User1825 $\left(z - n\right)! \to \infty$ whenever $z \to k$ for $k = n + 1, n + 2, n + 3, \ldots$.